# React Native TvOS TabBarIOS: How can I programatically navigate to different TabBarIOS item

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tvos

I have two different Items in my TabBarIOS, "Now Playing" and "Animations"

```
const TvApp = () => {
  const nowPlaying = useRef();

  return (
    <TabBarIOS showHideTransition={true}>
      <Item
        title="Now Playing"
        ref={nowPlaying}>
        <View>
          <Clock />
          <Video loopable={loopable} />
        </View>
      </Item>
      <Item title="Animations" showHideTransition={true}>
        <Animations setLoopable={setLoopable} nowPlaying={nowPlaying} />
      </Item>
    </TabBarIOS>
  );
};
```

[image: TabBar]

In my "Animations" screen, there's an `<Animations/>` component.

```
const Animations = ({nowPlaying}) => {
  const goToNowPlaying = () => {
    // How do I navigate to Now Playing when this is pressed?
    // 
  }

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      {Object.values(images).map(image => (
        <View style={styles.tile} key={image}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={goToNowPlaying}>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      ))}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

When I press on one of the items in this component, I want to navigate to the "Now Playing" screen. How do I do this? I've been looking at the docs for `TabBarIOS` and `TabBarIOS.item` and can't find anything. I've passed in a ref to the "Now Playing" item but can't simulate a click or onpress event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nowPlaying.current.props.onPress();` to navigate to the "Now Playing" Screen when item pressed in screen.

```
const Animations = ({nowPlaying}) => {
  const goToNowPlaying = () => {
    nowPlaying.current.props.onPress(); // <-- assuming the nowPlaying ref is for button or link
  }

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      {Object.values(images).map(image => (
        <View style={styles.tile} key={image}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={goToNowPlaying}>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      ))}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

for more info go through [these docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity)

Comment: Hmm this doesn't work. I'd have to define an `onPress` on the `nowPlaying` `Item`, what should I set `onPress` to?

All I have on `nowPlaying.current.props` is this:  `{"children": <View><Clock /><Video loopable={4} /></View>, "title": "Now Playing"}`